# std::vector buffer throwing bad_alloc in TCP socket code

Tags: c++, tcp, std

I am trying to send and receive a string using a TCP socket. I found some code online and modified it. Here is my sendString and receiveString code:

```
static inline void sendString(int socket, std::string s) {  
    size_t size = s.size();  
    size_t size_size = sizeof(size_t);  // We make our buffer: 
    std::vector<char> buffer(size + size_size);  // Put the size at the front:  
    char* size_begin = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size);  
    std::copy(size_begin, size_begin + size_size, &(buffer[0]));  // Copy the string data:  
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), &(buffer[size_size]));  // And finally send it:  
    send(socket, &buffer, size + size_size, 0); 
}

std::string receiveString(int socket) {  
    size_t size_size = sizeof(size_t);  
    size_t size;  // We read the size: 
    recv(socket, (char*)&size, size_size, 0);
    std::vector<char> buffer(size);  /** XXX: BAD ALLOC*/
    recv(socket, &buffer[0], size, 0);
    return std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
}
```

When I try to have my client send an actual string, the server side throws a std::bad_alloc in receiveString where indicated by a comment. Why did similar code work in sendString but not in receiveString? What is causing the bad::alloc issues? Also, would my code work for sending and receiving a string over a TCP socket?

Thanks!

Comment: In `sendString`, `&buffer` ==> `bufer.data()`. Beyond that, this code is rife with a lack of any critical error checking. Assuming code "just works", and thus violating [Spencer's 6th Commandment](https://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html) is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @WhozCraig I made this change, and it is still throwing the same error on the same line. Do you have any idea what else might be causing the problem?

Comment: Note `recv` gives no guarantees that you read the requested number of bytes. It just guarantees that you won't read more. So `recv(socket, (char*)&size, size_size, 0);` might have only read 0 to 3 bytes of `size_size` into `size` resulting in a completely bogus `size`  being used in `std::vector<char> buffer(size);`. Always consult the return value from `recv` and loop until you've received the correct number of bytes (or it becomes impossible to do so). The `MSG_WAITALL` option can also be helpful, at risk of the `recv` blocking forever waiting for all of the data to arrive.

Comment: Also note that `send` is similar. If you don't check the return value, you can't be sure that you really did send all of the data you wanted to. In general, never ignore a return code. If a programmer spent the time returning a value, it's probably important.

Comment: `std::cout << size << std::endl;` , appropriately placed in both functions, will probably tell you something significant. All part of *debugging*. (and yes, an actual *debugger* would be even *more* informative). Regardless, **error checking**. It is literally a fools errand to write socket code without it.

Comment: *0 to 3 bytes of `size_size`* And there's me foolishly assuming 32 bits. Should have just written *less than `size_size` bytes* instead of trying to sound all smart.

Answer (score 2):

In `sendString()`, you are not passing the prepared `vector` content to `send()` correctly. You need to change `&buffer` to either `&(buffer[0])` or `buffer.data()` instead.

That being said, the `vector`s are completely unnecessary in `sendString()` and `recvString()`.  Just call `send()`/`recv()` multiple times, you can send/receive the `size_t` and `string` separately, and let the socket handle the buffering of bytes for you.

For that matter, `send()` and `recv()` are not guaranteed to actually send/receive the requested buffer in one go.  You have to pay attention to their return values, calling them in loops until all bytes have actually been sent/received.

Also, you are not taking into account that different platforms have different sizes and endians for multi-byte integers.  So you need to handle that better, too.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
static inline void sendRaw(int socket, const void *buffer, size_t bufsize) {
    const char *ptr = static_cast<const char*>(buffer);
    while (bufsize > 0) {
        int numSent = send(socket, ptr, bufsize, 0); 
        if (numSent < 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("send failed");
        ptr += numSent;
        bufsize -= numSent;
    }
}

static inline void sendUint32(int socket, uint32_t value) {
    value = htonl(value);
    sendRaw(socket, &value, sizeof(value));
}

static inline void sendString(int socket, const std::string &s) {  
    size_t size = s.size();
    if (size > std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max())
        throw std::runtime_error("string is too long in length");
    sendUint32(socket, static_cast<uint32_t>(size));
    sendRaw(socket, s.c_str(), size);
}


static inline void recvRaw(int socket, void *buffer, size_t bufsize) {
    char *ptr = static_cast<char*>(buffer);
    while (bufsize > 0) {
        int numRecv = recv(socket, ptr, bufsize, 0); 
        if (numRecv < 0) throw std::runtime_error("recv failed");
        if (numRecv == 0) throw std::runtime_error("peer disconnected");
        ptr += numRecv;
        bufsize -= numRecv;
    }
}

static inline uint32_t recvUint32(int socket) {
    uint32_t value;
    recvRaw(socket, &value, sizeof(value));
    return ntohl(value);
}

std::string receiveString(int socket) {  
    uint32_t size = recvUint32(socket);
    std::string s;
    if (size > 0) {
        s.resize(size);
        recvRaw(socket, &s[0], size);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::bad_alloc` is thrown when the system can't allocate the requested memory. Most likely - the `size` is too big.

My crystal ball tells me that you may witness an issue with endianness. I would convert [host-to-network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-htonl) going up, and [network-to-host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-ntohll) on receive.

**UPDATE:**

As was pointed in multiple comments, if your call to `recv()` fails, the `size` will contain uninitialized garbage. You need to do two things to avoid that: initialize `size` with `0` **AND** check if `recv()` succeeded

Comment: You were right. I checked my received size and it is 140737347470944. However, the real problem was actually caused by me using the wrong socket fd for the server recv() code. My bad.

Comment: @AmyLi it is still in your interests to religiously check the return codes. Inspecting the return value, followed by a call to [`perror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror) or whatever provides network diagnostic error messages on your target platform, would have told you where to start looking if not how to solve the problem outright. If you don't check for errors you'll always be surprised by errors.